# Need to compare file Id for file uploading in java bean(old file and new file)

Tags: java, ejb, javabeans

I am newbie in java. I need some suggestion that checking file already existing in folder if not exist then upload file else message in java.

**Please give me some example**

I have done this let me know how to compare old object and new object.

```
public Reaction updateEchemReaction(Reaction reaction) {
    LOGGER.info("updateEchemReaction(Reaction reaction) called");
    entityManager.find(Reaction.class, reaction);
    Reaction oldObject = entityManager.find(Reaction.class, reaction);
    System.out.println("oldObject==========>>"+oldObject.getFileUpload());
    try {
         //if (oldObject == null) {
         if (reaction != null && reaction.getFileUpload() != null
                && reaction.getFileUpload().size() > 0) {

            Set<UUID> fileids = filesUploadBean.updateFiles(
                    reaction.getFileUpload(), reaction.getLabId());

            Set<UUID> fileidsNew = new HashSet<>();

            fileidsNew.addAll(fileids);

            if (reaction.getFileIds() != null) {
                fileidsNew.addAll(reaction.getFileIds());
            }

            reaction.setFileIds(fileidsNew);

        }
        //}
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if folder exists && file exist or not, where
      filePathHere- folder to check

```
File f = new File(filePathHere);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) 
   { 
   /* upload file code method and return boolean success/failure */ 

  }
else
  {
 /* return boolean success/failure or custom exception or  */ 
    }
```

// Compare objects - implement Comparable  and implmement compareTo method, not in code below but add null checks too, check ids or whatever java class fields you like.

```
public int compareTo(Reaction other) {
    int i = firstField.compareTo(other.firstField);
    if (i != 0) return i;

    i = secondField.compareTo(other.secondField);
    if (i != 0) return i;

    return Integer.compare(field3, other.field3);
}
```

Comment: Your code, question & above comment don't match.Its not very clear what help you want. Can you update your question with what you have tried, what exactly is problem and what help you want. What is this Reaction class and do you have field or timestamps somewhere that uniquely identify files?

Comment: how to upload a file without extension using javascript

Comment: $(':file').change(function(){
      var file = this.files[0];
      size = file.size;
      var sFileName = file.name;
      var reg = new RegExp(/(.exe|.sh)$/i);
      file = file.replace(/\\/g, '/');
      var fname = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/')+1, file.lastIndexOf('.'));
      if(reg.test(sFileName)) {
       alert("Please make sure your file extension should not be in exe or sh.");
      } else if(size &gt; 15728650) {
    alert("File size should not exceed 15 MB");
      } else {
       blockPage();
       $('#upload\\:hiddenSave11').click();
      }
  });